# How to catch the data from HTML code, writing code into XSLT?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

```html
<div class="content-tab-info-section-container-left">
  <div class="content-tab-info-section-img">
    <img alt="GARANTIE SUR LES MAT&#201;RIELS CONNECT&#201;S &#192; HAUTEUR DE 2&#160;000&#160;&#8364;" src="https://www.belkin.com/resources/img/cew/Belkin_CEW_icon_291x291_v2_2000eu.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="content-tab-info-section-txt">
    <h2>GARANTIE SUR LES MAT&#201;RIELS CONNECT&#201;S &#192; HAUTEUR DE 2&#160;000&#160;&#8364;</h2>
    <p>Le chargeur &#224; induction BOOST&#8593;UP&#8482;&#160;Stand (10&#160;W) pour appareils Apple, Samsung, LG et Sony est prot&#233;g&#233; par une garantie sur les mat&#233;riels connect&#233;s Belkin. Si votre dispositif est endommag&#233; par une
      recharge &#233;lectrique alors qu&#8217;il &#233;tait correctement connect&#233; au chargeur, Belkin le r&#233;parera ou le remplacera &#224; hauteur de 2&#160;000&#160;&#8364;. <br/>
      <a external-link="true" href="http://www.belkin.com/fr/support-article?articleNum=291991" style="color:#73D44A;" target="&#8221;_blank&#8221;">En savoir plus</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the above HTML code, I want to catch the data inside "P" tag using XSLT code. Could any help me to write the code how I should catch the data inside

tag using XSLT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows all `<P>` values no matter where they are in an original `XML` document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>Catched all P tags</h2>
    <xsl:for-each select="//p">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this is correct, but I am working on a certain condition. Firstly we need to inside of <div class="content-tab-info-section-container-left"> than <div class="content-tab-info-section-txt"> than we need to catch <p> element.

Comment: @BrajeshNarayan Why isn't all this in your question?

Comment: @BrajeshNarayan Can You please explain it more on which conditions You want to filter `p` tags?